# Get enclosing IJavaElement

Tags: methods, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I am working with the selections within the Eclipse source code editor. I defined a key-binding that gets me the "text" at the current caret position. I managed to parse the current caret position to an IJavaElement

```
private void processEditorSelection(IEditorPart part, ITextSelection selection) {
          IEditorInput editorInput = ((IEditorPart) part).getEditorInput();
            final ITypeRoot root = (ITypeRoot) JavaUI.getEditorInputJavaElement(editorInput);
            if (root != null) {
               int offset = (selection).getOffset();
                IJavaElement[] codeSelect = root.codeSelect(offset, 0);
                if (codeSelect.length > 0) {
                    //codeSelect[0...n] are my resolved elements at the current caret pos.
       }
```

What I did not managed to figure out yet is, how to resolve the enclosing type. for instance:

```
public void do() {
       System.out.println("it"); 
}
```

If the caret is on the System.out, I obtain an JavaElement of the system out call, but I am actually interested in the enclosing method. Does anyone know how to ask Eclipse for the enclosing type? Like what is the compilation unit or method my current carret position is enclosed in?

Thanks for an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to do something like this:

```
ITypeRoot root = (ITypeRoot) JavaUI.getEditorInputJavaElement(editorInput);
IJavaElement elt = root.getElementAt(caretPosition);
```

This will find the enclosing element, which may be an `IField`, `IMethod`, or `ICompilationUnit`.  To get the enclosing type, call this:

```
IType type = (IType) elt.getAncestor(IJavaElement.TYPE);
```

This method returns null if there is no enclosing type.